# Fixing two strings on an android TextView

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I'm trying to get the app version and display it on a TextView with an strings that is on my strings.xml. This is the code I have:

```
PackageManager manager = AboutActivity.this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = null;

try {
    info = manager.getPackageInfo(
            AboutActivity.this.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final TextView versionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.versionTextView);
String version_number = info.versionName;

versionTextView.setText(R.string.version + version_number);
```

It gets correctly the version number, but with this code, the TextView shows: `21310996911.0` When it should show `Version: 1.0`
Do somebody know how could I fix it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
versionTextView.setText(R.string.version + version_number);
```

to

```
versionTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.version) + version_number);
```